# Dynamic param in vue's template mustage tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There are columns in my DB named like 'h_01', 'h_02' ... 'h_23'.
In vue template I try to use this construction:

```
<td v-for="hour in hours">{{'item.h_'+hour}}</td>
```

But as the result I see only "item.h_1" in table cells, but not the real value from DB.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the FF screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you check your *hours* array? Please print it here

Comment: Hours - is an array like this [8, 9, 10, 12]. Item - is an object, like {h_01:22, h_02: 17, h_13: 99}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```js
{{ item["h_" + String(hour).padStart(2, '0')] }}
```

Comment: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Object, got Array

Comment: Pay attention to the cases with just one digit (you need h_01 and not h_1). A possible solution is using leftPad.

Comment: now, handled for one digit value of `hour`, thanks @MatheusValenza

Comment: Thank you!! {{ item["h_" + String(hour).padStart(2, '0')] }}